# Sharepoint: How to enable a field when a check box is selected on new item form?

Tags: 2010, list, custom-list, custom-field-types

In Sharepoint, I need modify a new item form of a list to make a field visible/invisible when a check box is selected:

For example:
There is a checkbox field called "Is XYZ affected?"

When a user selects this field, it will make a hidden field visible "Impact details:"

If "Is XYZ affected?" field is not checked, then "Impact details:" field is invisible.

This is easy to do it in html using javascript, how do I do it on Sharepoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in sharepoint either by directly modifying the page in sharepoont designer or by placing a content editor webpart on the page and writing the javascript/jquery code in it. Here is a sample: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/09/sharepoint-showhide-list-column-based.html

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom InfoPath form with conditional fields.
[Here is a helpful link.](http://designshare.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/creating-conditonally-required-fields-in-infopath/)

---

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/08/20/a-dummies-guide-to-sharepoint-and-jqueryndashgetting-amp-setting-sharepoint.aspx       this may help!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using the Jquerry, Follow this blog.
http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2013/08/walkthrough-conditionally-hide-fields.html